# maven: module needs to have a different version then the parent

Tags: maven

I have the following maven multi-module project:

The parent:

```
<!--parent-->
<groupId>my.project</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>4.2.9</version>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>my.deps</groupId>
  <artifactId>dep1</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
...
```

The module:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>my.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.9</version>
</parent>
<groupId>org.apache.karaf.examples</groupId>
<artifactId>apache-karaf-examples</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
```

When I build, the parent will refer to my.deps:dep1:1.0-SNAPSHOT, which doesn't exist, instead of my.deps:dep1:4.2.9. How could I make it refer to the correct version, i.e. my.deps:dep1:4.2.9, knowing that I can't modify the parent ?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Seymour

Answer (score 0):

You can try what happens when you declare the whole dependency *again* in the child project. I am not sure which of the two declarations will win.

If this does not help, you need to modify the parent POM.